# Assign method name to Func by string

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

basically I want to do this:

```
Func<string> f =  ()=> MyMethodName();
```

only having a string name of a method, i.e.:

```
 Func<string> f =  "MyMethodName";
```

Can this be done? Any problems, caveats? Can Reflection help? Can I first check if a method exist?

Comment: Do you want to always look for `MyMethodName` as a static or instance member of the current class, or might you be needing to call a method of another object?

Comment: @hvd, it might be a method of another object. Currently my method looks like this: Private string MyMethodName() { return new List<string>(); }

Comment: Then it gets a lot more complicated than the `GetMethod("MyMethodName")` that you've got in your answers so far. Or will you be able to pass the instance of the object directly?

Comment: If `"MyMethodName"` is known at compile time, you might prefer to use the `dynamic` keyword.  E.g. `dynamic d = myObj; Func<string> f = () => d.MyMethodName();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a lambda expression at all here. You can use [`Delegate.CreateDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.createdelegate.aspx):

```
MethodInfo method = GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
Func<string> func = (Func<string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>),
                                                           obj, method);
```

That way you avoid a level of indirection, and you also do the reflection part *once* instead of on every invocation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with reflection:

```
Func<string> func = ( ) => {
    return ( string )( this.GetType( ).GetMethod( "MyMethodName" ).Invoke( this, new object[ 0 ] ) );
}
```

If you want something to ease this thing here is something:

```
public static Func<string> ReflectByName( object obj, string methodname ) {
    return ( ) => {
        return ( string )( obj.GetType( ).GetMethod( methodname ).Invoke( obj, new object[ 0 ] ) );
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
Func<string> f = FastReflect.ReflectByName( this, "MyMethodName" );
```

`FastReflect` where is the method `ReflectByName` is in.

Comment: FastReflect is a bit misleading because this will be the slowest way to do this.

Comment: @MikeKulls It's doesn't talking about performance. It's about lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it. This has the advantage of being massively faster than reflection so is great if you need to call it in a loop. This code creates a Func that will call your method

```
    public static Func<T, string> CreateCallFunc<T>(string methodName)
    {
        var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var call = Expression.Call(parm, typeof(T).GetMethod(methodName));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(call, parm);
        return (Func<T, string>)lambda.Compile();
    }
```

you use it like this:

```
    class SomeClass
    {
        void DoIt()
        {
            var func = CreateCallFunc<SomeClass>("SomeMethod");
            Console.WriteLine(func(this));
        }

        public string SomeMethod()
        {
            return "it works!";
        }
    }
```

The big advantage is that once you have created your Func, you can call it very simply just using func(myInstance) and it will be very fast.

I use this method for taking a DataReader and copying all the data from the reading into a collection of classes where the property names on the class match the fields in the reader.

Note that John's answer is a much easier way to do this, which I wasn't aware of until now, but this has greater flexibility I guess